# HTML newsletter - Overlay text on various parts of an image, possibly using tables

Tags: html, css

We're trying to make an HTML newsletter with an image background of a scroll (something like http://images.clipartpanda.com/blank-scroll-clip-art-ancient-parchment-scroll-Download-Royalty-free-Vector-File-EPS-2942.jpg), and would like to have the ability to place text in specific areas of it. Ideally, we'd like to be able to easily place text in the top area (the rolled up section), in the middle, or at the bottom (again, in the rolled up section).

What's the best way to do this? We were experimenting with using the image as a background to a table, and using table cells to try to line up with the image areas, but struggled to get this to work.

Should we be trying to split the image into three separate images (top, middle, bottom) and using these as backgrounds for a table with three rows, or is that likely to not work well?

Apologies for our ignorance. Our HTML skills aren't really there; we just want a simple layout that we can use for newsletters.

EDIT: Here's what we're currently trying:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="height: 600px; width: 600px; background-image: url(http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qiB/orL/qiBorL8gT.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% 100%; background-origin: content-box">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="">&nbsp;
                    <table style="height: 500px; width: 400px; margin: auto;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr style="height: 100px;">
                                <td>This is some text in the top area</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="height: 400px;">
                                <td>This is the main text</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr style="height: 100px;">
                                <td>This is some text in the bottom area</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

I appreciate that this might be the wrong approach these days, though; what would be a better approach? Is this really outdated now?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow . Please provide some code http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Stackoverflow will help you solve problems but not do the work for you. I tip i would have is to not use tables, this is a thing of the past.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We've posted what we're currently trying, which sort of seems to work but seems sub-optimal. If tables aren't what you'd recommend for this kind of thing, what would be a better approach?

Comment: Tables may be a thing of the past in web development, but that isnt the case if you are planning on sending this newsletter by email, Tables HAVE to be used.